# problems with google code prettify for printing java code having code like List<Map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, html, google-code-prettify

I'm trying to print below line on html page:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> someVar = someMethod();
```

however, in html `Map<String,Object>` is being treated as  tag in html

Below is the output I'm getting:

```
List> someVar = someMethod();
```

everything else other than Map is being properly replaced by span tags

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

```
List&lt;Map&lt;String,Object&gt;&gt; someVar = someMethod();
```

Comment: Give this package a try: [link](http://developer.torello.directory/JavaHTML/javadoc/index.html)  It can **pretty-print** a single file using the _HiLiteMe.prettyPrintScrape(file, type, style)_ method - or it can **pretty-print** an entire directory tree - using the _FileNode_ class and a call to _HiLiteMe.prettyPrintRecursiveTree(FileNode, params)_.  It is based 100% off of the website http://HiLite.ME - and actually does a web-scrape to utilize their (pretty extensive) pretty-print engine.

Answer (score 1):

try inserting \r right after the <

`<script>
document.write("List <\rMap<\rString,Object>> someVar = someMethod();");
</script>`

the result I got was: List < Map< String,Object>> someVar = someMethod();